# Why are there no "even" harmonics in AC machines?

Tags: electric-machine, harmonics

Why are there no "even" harmonics in AC machines?
In Chapman's book, he says it's because of symmetry of the flux density wave but I don't get it...

Comment: Even harmonics imply the positive and negative half cycles are somehow different. Draw a sinewave. Draw its 2nd harmonic. Draw their sum and you'll get it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond This source (https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/harmonics.html), under the figure titled "Complex Waveforms Due to Harmonics", does just as you had suggested, and the result of that summation between the 1st and 2nd harmonic shows a non-zero output waveform. Would you care to elaborate why positive and negative half cycles being different would somehow result in a lack of a harmonic?

Comment: @plu no, positive and negative half cycles being THE SAME implies the lack of even harmonics. Note your linked illustration (2nd harmonic) shows the half cycles being different, supporting this.

Comment: That makes more sense given the inputs of AC machines almost always have symmetrical positive and negative half cycles, thanks.

Comment: As other have said, whenever the waveform is symmetrical about the time axis (or equivalently, when the first half cycle is the negative of the second half cycle), which is known as _half-wave symmetry_, all even harmonics are zero. This answers a "when", and partly the "why" of the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You know that a square wave with perfect symmetry has NO EVEN harmonics. (typo fixed)

You can imagine if a magnetic material had a "hard saturation" limit instead of a "Landau"? curve with hysteresis, you would get a square wave current for a sine wave voltage.  **Thus all the current is fundamental & odd harmonics.** But with a symmetrical soft saturation curve the harmonics are attenuated. **The harmonics increase as the current enters the soft saturation region, yet still remain ODD multiples as long as the non-linear soft saturation curve is symmetrical .**

[image]

Thus the only time you would get even harmonics in a magnetic material is if there was remanence such as from DC bias.  Then the voltage swing produces more  asymmetrical current and no longer is  a symmetrical soft square wave but asymmetrical even harmonic producing fourier components of the distorted waveform. Then the apparent inductance drops quickly and is usually rated for -10% at rated DC or ac current.

Normally large transformers experience remenance from abrupt disconnects and flux  leakage resistance balances the current after several seconds which is apparent by the hum of large MVA transformers during reconnect. This is why "smart reclosures" remember the phase of disconnect and reclose at exactly the same phase to minimize Remenance and saturation currents that produce many forces inside transformers and even harmonics.

To visualize fourier components with a hand-drawn waveform or std. waveform try this **[java](http://falstad.com/fourier/)** app. then choose boxes for mag/phase and log view and change the frequency spikes with mouse and see the effects on time domain signal. Note the absence of even harmonics in both a square wave and a triangle wave but the phase is different in each harmonic.

Comment: A symmetrical square wave has only odd harmonics not "no odd harmonics" tony

Comment: dyslexic like typo, corrected

Answer (score 0):

Any wave forms can be represented by Fourier series,

F(x) = Ao + Summation n=1 to n (An Cos nx + Bn Sin nx) and when the wave form is symmetrical, which means that the positive and negative half cycle are identical, when calculating An and Bn constant, integrating from 0 to Pi, when n is even number, you can get the result that An=Bn=0, therefore, as soon as any wave form positive and negative cycle are identical, the even order harmonic is not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following Matlab code demo. `x`, `z`, and `q` are three simulated magnetic fields. `x` is comprised only of odd harmonics. `z` is a distortion of `x` by the addition of even harmonics. `q` is the sum of `x` with a DC magnetic field (bias). For each of these, the time series and the Fourier transform magnitude and phase are plotted. Furthermore, at the end, I have plotted the magnetic flux density as a function of a hypothetical magnetic field strength (the hysteresis loop).

You'll find that `z` transforms from a square wave to a sawtooth as the strength of the even harmonics gets larger. We can back out the magnetic field strength that would generate a hypothetical sawtooth flux density by differentiating the sawtooth waveform. By doing this, we find that the field strength has the pattern of an impulse train. On the other hand, adding a DC bias to `x` only adds a DC term to the Fourier transform; no even harmonics are introduced. Thus it seems that periodic spikes in the current applied to a transformer would generate even harmonics.

The source of these spikes is still uncertain to me. Perhaps, they might be generated as artifacts if the core is fully saturated and additional magnetic field strength is still applied. When the core reaches saturation, the amplifier generating the signal experiences no more back EMF, and because it is still driving current with the same voltage, it could result in a sudden spike. It's sort of like walking in the opposite direction of a moving walkway. Right when you get off, you experience a sudden jerk because your legs are still applying the same force to keep you going forward (and then you correct yourself). This jerk is like the spike in current. This is just a guess, and I would appreciate any feedback on this response.

```
clear; close all

%% Generate signal

nharodd = 100;
Fs = 1E3;
t = 0:1/Fs:10-1/Fs;
X = nan(length(t), nharodd);
for i = 1:nharodd
    X(:, i) = 1/(2*i-1)*sin(2*pi*(2*i-1)*5*t);
end
x = sum(X, 2);
figure(1); subplot(3, 1, 1); plot(t, x)
xlabel('Time (s)'); ylabel('B (T)')

Y = fftshift(fft(x));
L = size(Y, 1);
P1 = 2*abs(Y/L);
P1((length(P1))/2+1) = P1((length(P1))/2+1)/2;
phs = angle(Y); phs(P1 < 1E-4) = 0;
f = Fs*(-L/2:(L/2)-1)/L;

subplot(3, 1, 2); plot(f, P1, 'r')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('B (T)');
subplot(3, 1, 3); plot(f, phs, 'r')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('Phase (radians)')

%% Modify signal by adding some even harmonic components

nhareven = 100;
Z = nan(length(t), nhareven);
for i = 0:100
    for j = 1:nhareven
        Z(:, j) = 1/(2*j)*sin(2*pi*(2*j)*5*t);
    end
    z = x + i*0.01*sum(Z, 2);
    figure(2); subplot(3, 1, 1); plot(t, z)
    xlabel('Time (s)'); ylabel('B (T)')
    title(sprintf('Relative strength of even harmonics: %2.2f', 0.01*i))

    Y = fftshift(fft(z));
    L = size(Y, 1);
    P1 = 2*abs(Y/L);
    P1((length(P1))/2+1) = P1((length(P1))/2+1)/2;
    phs = angle(Y); phs(P1 < 1E-4) = 0;
    f = Fs*(-L/2:(L/2)-1)/L;

    subplot(3, 1, 2); plot(f, P1, 'r')
    xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('B (T)');
    subplot(3, 1, 3); plot(f, phs, 'r')
    xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('Phase (radians)')

    pause(0.01)
end

figure; yyaxis left; plot(t, [0; diff(z)*Fs]);
xlabel('Time (s)'); ylabel('H (A/m)')
yyaxis right; plot(t, cumtrapz([0; diff(z)*Fs]))
ylabel('B-hat (T)')

%% Add DC bias to B

q = x + 0.5;

figure; subplot(3, 1, 1); plot(t, q);
xlabel('Time (s)'); ylabel('B (T)')

Y = fftshift(fft(q));
L = size(Y, 1);
P1 = 2*abs(Y/L);
P1((length(P1))/2+1) = P1((length(P1))/2+1)/2;
phs = angle(Y); phs(P1 < 1E-4) = 0;
f = Fs*(-L/2:(L/2)-1)/L;

subplot(3, 1, 2); plot(f, P1, 'r')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('B (T)');
subplot(3, 1, 3); plot(f, phs, 'r')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)'); ylabel('Phase (radians)')

%% Visualize hysteresis loops for a sinusoidal input

% H leads B
h = sin(2*pi*5*t - pi/10);

figure; plot(h, x)
hold on; plot(h, z)
plot(h, q)
xlabel('H (A/m)'); ylabel('B(T)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out when even/odd harmonics appear on your own by using the applet below:
https://www.falstad.com/fourier/

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question was "why", not "when".

Answer (score -4):

Because of the magnetization characteristics of the iron. It has nothing to do witth symetry, the inductivity of the iron core choke is nonlinear due to the magnetization characteristics. This leads to the distortion of the signal, which add some harmonic components. The shape of characteristics determines the type of distortion.

Comment: it has everything to do with symmetry